# cakephp 2.2.2 database connection with mssql sql server

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to connect `CakePHP 2.2.2` stable version with `MS SQL` database.

Below is db connection that I'm using:

```
public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mssql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => '192.192.1.1',
    'login' => 'username',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'dbname',
    'prefix' => '',
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
```

When I connect with CorePHP - it works, So all credentials I use are correct however when I connect with CakePHP 2.2.2 version, returns below error:

```
Cake is NOT able to connect to the database.
Datasource class Mssql could not be found.
```

I have following files in my dbo library on path: `cakephp/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/Database`

```
Mysql.php
Postgres.php
Sqlite.php
Sqlserver.php
```

So I believe that all files required for `MS SQL Server` connection is present in my Cake version.

Let me know what I am missing or having problem with.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: no buddy, still the same issue.. did not work with any help or changes found from internet, finally decided to go off cakephp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the correct datasource string is 'Sqlserver' and not 'mssql'.

Answer (score 0):

The **Sqlserver** datasource depends on **Microsoft’s** PHP extension called pdo_sqlsrv. This PHP Extension is not included in the base installation of PHP and must be installed separately.

Also the SQL Server Native Client must be installed for the extension to work. As the Native Client is available **only for Windows** you will not be able to install it on Linux, Mac OS X or FreeBSD.